# Recovering from a boot loop (Samsung S9 Plus) ... which CSC?

Tags: samsung, recovery-mode, samsung-galaxy-s-9

I am currently stuck in a boot loop with my Samsung S9 Plus. The phone in question can be booted into recovery and download mode, but that's about it.

I found that I should be able to use Frija or SamFirm to download the latest update, but it prompts me for the CSC. Now I understand what the CSC is supposed to be, but how do I find the appropriate one?

In my case the phone was bought in Germany, but initially it showed stuff in Italian when turning it on. So which CSC should I use? Or does it actually not matter at all?

Would it be okay to go with `DBT` (Germany, unbranded) [as per this list](https://www.droidviews.com/how-to-change-csc-in-samsung-galaxy-phones/#G)?

I didn't by the phone from the carrier, but on the free market.

**NB:** since the system is in a boot loop it's too late to look up the proper CSC.

Comment: @alecxs thanks. But what are these supposed to mean? I know Frija (mentioned it in my question) and Odin. But that doesn't tell me which CSC I should give if I have no way to retrieve the current value during a boot loop ...

Comment: @alecxs I tried flashing TWRP and that failed, no matter whether it was a patched or pristine ODIN. And on the download mode screen I don't see a model number. Besides, the model number is not what my question is about, my question is about the appropriate CSC. I went with DBT in the end ... so far it's working.